# making a SOAP request not working

Tags: php, soap

I am having this issue for more than a week now without being able to find a solution to it. I an trying to make a SOAP call where the required structure of the request is

```
        <xs:element name="getMismatchRequest">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="LoginInfo" type="LoginInfoType"/>
                    <xs:element name="UserInput" type="UserInputType"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:complexType name="LoginInfoType">
            <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="userName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="password" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:complexType name="UserInputType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="panNo" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="asseessmentyear" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
```

I have tried various ways, using SoapClient & nusoap as well, to send the 'getMismatchRequest' but its not been working.

Nothing has been working for me.

This is my code using SoapClient, the credentials I am using are the working ones.

```
$requestParams3 = array(
    'LoginInfo' => array(
        'userName' => 'XXXX', 
        'password' => 'XXXX'
    ),
    'addClient' => array(
        'addClientDetails' => array(
            'panNumber' => 'XXXX2323X',
            'dateOfBirth' => '1983-12-01',
            'email' => 'email@example.com'
        )
    )
);

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
        'cache_wsdl' => 0,
        "trace" => true,
        "exceptions" => false,
        "soap_version" => "SOAP_1_1"
    ));


    $response = $client->addClientDetails($requestParams3);
    print($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
    print($client->__getLastResponseHeaders());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print(json_encode($e));
}

print_r(json_encode($response));
```

I need help in getting the right way to make this request. My feeling is that I am making some mistake in constructing the complextype request patameter.

**EDIT:**
Sorry for missing the important part.

I get this error:

```
{"faultstring":"Authentication failed. Please provide a valid User ID and Password","faultcode":"ns0:Client"}
```

**SOME MORE INFO:**

I have also tried using the nusoap.php

this is the code :

```
    require_once('build/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);

$error = $client->getError();
if ($error) {
    echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}
$result = "";

$requestParams3 = array('getTaxCredMismatchRequest' => array(
    'LoginInfo' => array(
        'userName' => 'XXXX', 
        'password' => 'XXXX'
    ),
    'UserInput' => array(
        'panNo' => 'AGOPN8324J',
        'asseessmentyear' => '2014-15'
    ))
);

if ($client) {

    $client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
    $result = $client->call("getTaxCredMisMatch", $requestParams3);
}
if ($client->fault) {
    echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
} else {
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    } else {
        echo "<h2>zip code</h2><pre>";
        echo $result;
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}

echo "<h2>Request</h2>";
echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . "</pre>";
echo "<h2>Response</h2>";
echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . "</pre>";
```

The error :

```
    Fault

Array
(
    [faultcode] => ns0:Client
    [faultstring] => Array
        (
            [!xml:lang] => en
            [!] => Authentication failed. Please provide a valid User ID and Password
        )

)
Request

POST /e-FilingWS/ditws HTTP/1.0
Host: incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 719

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns9146="http://tempuri.org"><SOAP-ENV:Body><getTaxCredMismatchRequest xmlns="http://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/ditws/TaxCredMismatch/v_1_0"><LoginInfo xmlns=""><userName xmlns="">XXXX</userName><password xmlns="">XXXX</password></LoginInfo><UserInput xmlns=""><panNo xmlns="">AGOPN8324J</panNo><asseessmentyear xmlns="">2014-15</asseessmentyear></UserInput></getTaxCredMismatchRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
Response

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2015 01:47:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Accept: text/xml
Set-Cookie: ITDEFILING=701055076661; Path=/e-Filing/; HttpOnly; Secure
Via: 1.1 ID-0002262016415314 uproxy-4
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: Keep-alive
Via: 1.1 ID-0002262044274430 uproxy-4

<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header/><env:Body><env:Fault xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode>ns0:Client</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en">Authentication failed. Please provide a valid User ID and Password</faultstring></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Comment: "Not working" how?  If you are getting an error back, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that it works with a regular soap client like SoapUI or something similar?

Comment: It looks like you have login details for http://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in in there. Might want to take those off the internet.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I had removed it from places, but left it in the error message. Thanks again.

Comment: I havent verified it with SoapUI. I am not familiar to it. Very new to SOAP.

Comment: Getting SOAP to work can be tricky. I would say you definitely need to prove your login works via another client before you can blame PHP

Comment: Thanks @codenesium, I will definitely try that out. I had actually downloaded it but didnt try to use. Let me do it today evening and then get back with the results.